# Is there a way to shorten/override the stateToPropagate parameter from AuthProviderPluginClass methods?

Tags: apex, auth-provider, open-id-connect, authproviderpluginclass

Following the Apex structure of [AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm):

```
getCustomMetadataType()
Returns the custom metadata type API name for a custom OAuth-based authentication provider for single sign-on to Salesforce.

getUserInfo(authProviderConfiguration, response)
Returns information from the custom authentication provider about the current user. This information is used by the registration handler and in other authentication provider flows.

handleCallback(authProviderConfiguration, callbackState)
Uses the authentication provider’s supported authentication protocol to return an OAuth access token, OAuth secret or refresh token, and the state passed in when the request for the current user was initiated.

initiate(authProviderConfiguration, stateToPropagate)
Returns the URL where the user is redirected for authentication.

refresh(authProviderConfiguration, refreshToken)
Returns a new access token, which is used to update an expired access token.
```

There is this method `initiate(authProviderConfiguration, stateToPropagate)`
where the `stateToPropagate` param is the "state passed in to initiate the authentication request for the user."

So when executing the `initiate` method (via clicking the SSO button on Salesforce login page), I get the `Remote_Error: The remote service returned an error` where the error_description = `This is an invalid request`.

I found out that it was an invalid request because the third party Open ID Provider I am integrating with only allows the state to have the **max character limit of 255** whereas the Salesforce `stateToPropagate` is producing a state of **360 characters** 99% of the time (only once it somehow produce a 252 characters by dumb luck).

[image: stateToPropagate length]

Is there anyway, to get the `stateToPropagate` param to produce a shorter random String of 255 characters or below, OR is there a way to override the `stateToPropagate` param?

Comment: Can you help me on how you are capturing the stateToPropogate parameter in debug log?
I have to save that information temporarily in a custom field but I am struggling to understand how to capture this info first.
I can see you are able to capture in user debugs.
can you please help me?

Comment: After you create the AuthProviderPluginClass, then you need to Add it to your org's login page (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_org_login_page.htm&type=5) then just press the SSO button